# How to Execute Button B After A Button finished?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have Two Function A() And B(); i called A in Raised Button And B in another Raised Button

i need execute function B() after A() is finished when the user click on B before A I don't want anything happen

RaisedButton(
onPressed: A,
),
RaisedButton(
onPressed: B,
),

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a minimal reproducible example with code, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Buttons can be disabled by not providing an `onPressed` function. That way the button is visible, but it's grayed out and the user can't click it.

You can track, if the button is enabled or not with a field in your widget state.
For example:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  bool canDoB = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
            children: [
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("ButtonA"),
                onPressed: () {
                  // enable ButtonB
                  setState(() => canDoB = true);
                }
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("ButtonB"),
                onPressed: canDoB
                  // canDoB == true
                  ? () { print("pressedB"); }
                  // canDoB == false
                  : null
              )
            ]
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```